# Is it normal for clear resin to lose transparency after curing?

Tags: troubleshooting, resin, color, uv-printer

I am using a FORM LABS 3 printer with clear resin. After printing the model, I wash it with Isopropenyl and dry it. Then I cure it using Formlabs Form Cure for 5 minutes under 60 C°.
After curing the model, the clear print loses some of its transparency.

Is this normal? can it be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to most resins and the amount of haziness is directly related to the type of resin.  Not all clear resins do this mind you, but it has to do with the curing sprlectrum of light(natural sunlight cures do this way worse.)

Answer (score 1):

Clouding is a known issue with colored transparent resins, as is yellowing with clear resin.

Uncle Jessy did quite a good video explaining the issue and how to best avoid it.

The conclusion was that you should wash and dry them with as little UV exposure as possible (Drying them inside a box in a warm room rather than in direct sunlight), then coating them with Clear Coat lacquer or a similar product, then curing them.

[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ya0DSVYXsE&t=5s)